# IntegrityError at /cart/update-transaction/0cqydz1f/

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Hello am trying to make a transaction pressing submit this is the error am getting

> IntegrityError at /cart/update-transaction/0cqydz1f/ NOT NULL
>   constraint failed: shopping_cart_transaction.product_id Request
>   Method:   GET Request
>   URL:  http://localhost:8000/cart/update-transaction/0cqydz1f/ Django
>   Version:  2.2 Exception Type: IntegrityError Exception Value:  NOT NULL
>   constraint failed: shopping_cart_transaction.product_id

### models.py

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    token = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    order_id = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=100, decimal_places=2)
    success = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.order_id

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-timestamp']
```

### views.py

```html
    @login_required()
    def update_transaction_records(request, token):
        # get the order being processed
        order_to_purchase = get_user_pending_order(request)
    
        # update the placed order
        order_to_purchase.is_ordered=True
        order_to_purchase.date_ordered=datetime.datetime.now()
        order_to_purchase.save()
    
        # get all items in the order - generates a queryset
        order_items = order_to_purchase.items.all()
    
        # update order items
        order_items.update(is_ordered=True, date_ordered=datetime.datetime.now())
    
        # Add products to user profile
        user_profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, user=request.user)
        # get the products from the items
        order_products = [item.product for item in order_items]
        user_profile.ebooks.add(*order_products)
        user_profile.save()
    
    
        # create a transaction
        transaction = Transaction(profile=request.user.profile,
                                token=token,
                                order_id=order_to_purchase.id,
                                amount=order_to_purchase.get_cart_total(),
                                success=True)
        # save the transcation (otherwise doesn't exist)
        transaction.save()
    
        messages.info(request, "Thank you! Your purchase was successful!")
        return redirect(reverse('accounts:my_profile'))
```

Please help out am stuck here

Comment: Your `Transaction` model needs a `Product` object here `transaction = Transaction(profile=request.user.profile,
                    ....................................... product = product_obj)`. Cause `product` is not a `Null` field in your model.

Comment: thanks but cant find a way to define product_obj  to be the exact purchased product, since gives an error product_obj is not defined

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: tested see the error Cannot assign "<OrderItem: the 10x rule>": "Transaction.product" must be a "Product" instance.

Comment: Hey thanks solved it i had to iterate through the order_products and not order_items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your `transaction` in your `view`

I'm assuming your `order_products` is a list of all ordered `products`

```
for i in order_products:
    transaction = Transaction(profile=request.user.profile,
                                product=i,
                                token=token,
                                order_id=order_to_purchase.id,
                                amount=order_to_purchase.get_cart_total(),
                                success=True)
     # save the transcation (otherwise doesn't exist)
     transaction.save()
```

Comment: Still am getting this error Cannot assign "<OrderItem: the 10x rule>": "Transaction.product" must be a "Product" instance.

Comment: @Cipher where are the **products** in the view. Cause I thought order_items contained the list of products. Can you please point me to where the products are in the view

Comment: The order_items are products in the cart yet purchased,but the product  in transaction model means already purchased product, so i was thinking the transaction  should also contain the product name

Comment: solved  it  had to iterate for i in order_products:

Comment: @Cipher great. Will update the answer to reflect `order_products` then. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You haven't passed an argument for `product` as mentioned in your model. And since you have not given it a default value or `blank = True` is given you the NOT NULL constrained failed error.

```
product = models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Pass the product object here.

```
transaction = Transaction(profile=request.user.profile,product = product, ...)
```

Comment: product not defined how can i defined  product to query the purchased product am stuck